# Running Linux on RTL simulator

Tags: linux, operating-systems, linux-kernel, simulator

Is it possible to run Linux OS on RTL simulator.
If yes someone please help me in this regard.
I already tried running openrisc RTL code on de0-nano board. Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Not in any practical sense. RTL simulations are *extremely* slow -- they're intended as a tool for debugging the gate-level implementation of the processor itself, not as a system simulator. Booting the Linux kernel on an RTL simulation would likely take hours, if not days.